# How to load specific google chrome profile using c# & Selenium chrome driver?

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to load my current google chrome profile with all the extensions/cookies/logins & passwords for sites using C# & Selenium chrome driver.
Please help me to put correct code lines in the correct places.

I found some info how people did this with python , but even in those threads there are no answers where to put that code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
IWebDriver Browser;

public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


IWebElement element;

Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
Browser.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
Thread.Sleep(3000);

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Browser.Quit();
}
```

Code I provided successfully opens an empty google chrome profile. I need the selenium chrome driver to open google chrome with my google chrome profile instead of empty profile.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You can use the chromeoptions.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

Refer to the http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities, for more information.
Make sure to use the chrome option with driver.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Added this with path to my profile straight before this line.

Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();

Now i got this error:
Could not find the type or name of the namespace "ChromeOptions" (perhaps there is no using directive or a link to the assembly)

Comment: Refer to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm

Comment: added using; OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome , now all working again , but still opens an empty google chrome profile.

Here is path i added to user-data-dir=C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

This folder consist of 19 extensions folders , so think it's pasted correctly

What's going wrong?.

Comment: Remove `Default` at the end.

Comment: `chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")` and then lauched chrome `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)` in python and it opened a blank browser with all the extension that I am using.

Comment: Still can't understand what i'm doing wrong & what should i change to make this profile loaded =(

Comment: Ok, do this to check if your profile is loaded using the chromeoption. Open a new tab in the browser that was opened by webdriver, and then go to `chrome://version`. Check the value for `Profile Path`.

Comment: If you don't see the path what you specified in the chromeoptions, then there is something wrong with the code. Can you please add your chromeoptions steps to the post.

Comment: I checked. Webdriver's chrome Is located in C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\folder\folder
I've changed code at the start of this topic , so you can see how this looks now for me.

Comment: `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` is this how you are launching the browser.